# Why is the wrong region being sent to Amazon S3 bucket query?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I'm trying to stream music stored in an Amazon S3 bucket.

```
import boto3
SERVICE_NAME = 's3'
REGION_NAME = 'eu-west-2'

def generate_presigned_url(bucket_name, object_key, expiry=3600):
    client = boto3.client("s3",region_name=REGION_NAME,
               aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
               aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
     response =  client.generate_presigned_url(
             'get_object', 
              Params={'Bucket': bucket_name,
             'Key': object_key},
              ExpiresIn=expiry)
     return response

url = generate_presigned_url('bucket','music.mp3',3600)
print(url)
```

Output (reformatted so you can see...):

```
https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/music.mp3?
X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&
X-Amz-Credential=[redacted]%2Feu-west-[etc]
```

This is failing with the following error:

```
Error parsing the X-Amz-Credential parameter; 
the region 'eu-west-2' is wrong; expecting 'us-east-1'
```

Any ideas what is going wrong? The correct region is in the generated URL.

I've read everything I can find with this error, with no luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED.

It turns out the error message was a distration.

My error was not correctly creating the URL. Instead of:

`url = generate_presigned_url('bucket','music.mp3',3600)`

I needed to state the name of the bucket thus:

`url = generate_presigned_url(bucket_name,'music.mp3',3600)`

I hope that helps anyone else stuck on this error message.

Answer (score 3):

maybe the region in your [default] profile in the ~/.aws/credentials or ~/.aws/config is set to another and it's creating conflict ?

you could also try to set a config:

```
my_config = Config(
    region_name = 'us-west-2',
    signature_version = 'v4',
    retries = {
        'max_attempts': 10,
        'mode': 'standard'
    })
client = boto3.client('s3', config=my_config)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! My ~/.aws/config had the correct eu server, and adding the Config function didn't help either. There's something else going on... Cheers anyway!

Comment: For this to work you can add `from botocore.config import Config`.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code and got the same error.

Then, I changed your code to point to a bucket of mine in the `ap-southeast-2` region and got this error:

```
Error parsing the X-Amz-Credential parameter; the region 'eu-west-2' is wrong; expecting 'ap-southeast-2'
```

It is saying that I had the wrong `REGION_NAME` compared to the bucket that I was attempting to access.

Therefore, it would appear that the bucket you are referencing in `generate_presigned_url()` is *not* located in `eu-west-2`.

Comment: Thanks for trying it out. Did a sanity check: My bucket is definitely in eu-west-2. I’ll try creating a bucket in the US & see if the same code works there…

Comment: I created a bucket in us-east-1. The first thing to note is all buckets are accessible in all regions whatever you set REGION_NAME too. However, with REGION_NAME set to 'eu-west-2', I get the 'expecting 'us-east-1'' region in all buckets. WIth REGION_NAME set to 'us-east-1', I get an 'Access Denied" error. John, where you able to get a working URL from that code? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the code worked fine against my bucket in `ap-southeast-2`. Interestingly, the format of the presigned URL changed for that region, possibly because sigv4 is a requirement for `eu-west-2`.

Comment: Indeed, the url format is interesting. See my other answer. I got the code working by using the correct name for the bucket, instead of just 'bucket'. Doh!

Comment: You know, I suspected that, but thought "surely they've simply changed the bucket name for privacy". So much for assumptions! Glad you got it working.

Comment: lol me too. I assumed the error message was the problem. Then I read somewhere that generated s3 urls are not necessarily valid, and I thought I should go back and check how mine were being generated...